# Excel - Calculate the most optimal volumetric box dimensions for multiple packages

Tags: excel, excel-formula, volume, dimensions, product-quantity

I have multiple box dimensions and quantities in Excel, and need to be able to calculate the smallest box in which they can be shipped together.

Example 1:

| Package | Item | Quantity | Length | Height | Width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Package 1 | Box 1 | 2 | 48 | 78 | 50 |
| Package 1 | Box 2 | 2 | 4.1 | 28 | 11.5 |

Example 2:

| Package | Item | Quantity | Length | Height | Width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Package 2 | Box 1 | 10 | 48 | 78 | 50 |

Example 3:

| Package | Item | Quantity | Length | Height | Width |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Package 3 | Box 1 | 2 | 32 | 88 | 36 |
| Package 3 | Box 2 | 1 | 16 | 53 | 31 |
| Package 3 | Box 3 | 10 | 2 | 2 | 24 |

All of the information is in Excel and displayed in the columns like above.

I know that the result of each of these should be as follows:

Package 1 - 96 x 78 x 54.1

Package 2 - 240 x 100 x 78

Package 3 - 88 x 72 x 48

I am just unsure of the calculations required in order to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Can you explain how you calculate `123 x 56.2 x 56`?

Comment: Sorry, I have adjusted my figures....I had copied the wrong figures into my example!

Comment: This is not an Excel question, but a math question about packing. Once the math is worked out you want an Excel solution, but you need to solve the math first.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because at its core it is about [Mathematics.SE]